# Guessing Game in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is make a simple guessing game where the user can any the number without limit but will be graded at the end when the guessed the number correctly based on the number of their guesses. However, with my code when I enter a number and press the button to multiple times the hint changes from "Higher" to "Lower" even if the number is not changed also the message that should be displayed when the number is guessed correctly is not showing. Here's my code, I'm a beginner so there's bound to be errors in the code and any help is appreciated.

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="number" id="guess" />
    <button onClick="checknum();">Check Number</button>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>  
    <p>Your current status:</p>
    <output id="status_output">You have yet to guess anything.</output>
</fieldset> 

<script type="text/javascript">

    function checknum(){

        var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        var guessNumber = document.getElementById("guess").value;
        //var guessNumber = parseInt(guess.value);
        var statusOutput = document.getElementById('status_output');
        var counter = 0;    
        var isguessed = false;

        do {
            counter = (counter + 1)
            if (guessNumber < randomNumber) {
                statusOutput.value = ("Higher");
            }
            else if (guessNumber > randomNumber) {
                statusOutput.value = ("Lower");
            }
            else if (guessNumber = randomNumber) {
                set (isguessed = true());
                statusOutput.value = ("Correct" + mark());
            }
        }
        while (isguessed = false);
    }

    function mark(){
        if (counter < 10){
            statusOutput.value("Excellent");
        }
        else if (counter > 10 && counter <20){
            statusOutput.value("Okay");
        }
        else 
            statusOutput.value("Needs Practice");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: `while (isguessed = false)` should be `while (isguessed === false);` (3 equals instead of 1), same problem with all your last else if statement.

Comment: if you are going to use **statusOutput** in both functions, you should declare the variable outside of both functions, else it will not be accessible to `mark()`. See javascript closures https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: you are also using two ways to assign values to **statusOutput**, `statusOutput.value = ("Higher");` and `statusOutput.value("Excellent");`. The first way is correct; the second way is the 'jquery' style of assigning value, and will not work with vanilla javascript. You also do not have to place a bracket around a string in your first method, this is sufficient `statusOutput.value = "Higher";`

Comment: This will loop forever if you didn't guess the `Random Number`

Comment: How stop from looping if I didn't guess right?

Answer (score 0):

In your while you are assigning false to the variable named isguessed.
You want to do `while (isguessed === false)` instead. This will check if isguessed is set to false

`isguessed = false` : assigns the varibles isguessed to false

`isguessed === false` : a boolean expression return true or false